# Customizing upstart "restart" commands

Tags: upstart, init, init.d

I'd like to run a different command when upstart is restarting a process than when it is starting a process. In particular, I'm using Thin and I want to do a rolling restart (built in to thin via a different command) instead of stopping/starting.

Is this possible with upstart, or do I need to start looking for a different solution?

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible like that. Job itself doesn't know it is restarting.

I suggest you simply use two different jobs. `Job A` that does the first variant and `Job B` that starts up when `Job A` fails. There is extra information attached to `stopping`event of `Job A` in case it fails (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id109 ), so `Job B` should have `start on` stanza such as:

```
start on stopping JobA RESULT=failed
```

and

```
respawn
```

to keep it up. `respawn`should not be added to `Job A` at all.

This was the job will not start if `Job A` successfully exits, but only on an error condition.