# How can I tell inside an upstart script if the job was killed(crashed) or stopped normaly

Tags: upstart

Is there a way to know within the script if the job in question was killed(crashed) or stopped normaly.

I want to kill another process in post-stop script only when the current job crashed and not when it was stopped using stop "task-A"

Answer (score 1):

See my other answer: [Customizing upstart "restart" commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116964/customizing-upstart-restart-commands/117260#117260)

Make a task-B that has start condition as `start on stopping task-A RESULT=failed` and do the killing there, or just add to your to-be-killed job a stop gracefully on `stop on stopping task-A RESULT=failed`.

More in [Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id292).

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer to signal you have received help.